# Strange Sighting, Help Needed!

Tags: amateur-observing

I live in Hyderabad. Around a week ago, I, with my mother went to observe the planets from my roof I had observed Jupiter and Saturn till they went down below the horizon and then I was ready to move my telescope on Mars which was about just above my head. When I looked at it I saw a really strange 5 dotted flying thing fly a little towards the left of Mars. I asked my mother, and as she had sight and was not wearing spectacles, She didn't see it as 5 dots, but a thin straight line.
I know that it cannot be a rocket or jet plane as it left no trail, and it can't be  a plane or helicopter as it made no sound. I read a similar post about 2-3 weeks ago about a U.F.O collecting stars, but this was not at all like it. Could anyone tell me if it was anything known or if that is really an Undefined Flying Object?

Comment: What you describe is not an astronomical object.  We don't analyse UFO sightings, unless they appear to describe a misidentified astronomical object.  We don't know what you saw.  We don't know if you saw anything. We can't respond to UFO sightings.  But its probably a plane.

Comment: @JamesK should speak for JamesK and not for everyone. There is no "we" here except for the [Royal we](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we) and I don't think that that is what is intended.

Comment: @RyugaGod have a look at [Are there Starlink train-finding websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48032) and the answer there. Do you think it was some Starlink satellites? They definitely move in a straight line, though sometimes they cluster is a little staggered they still move together.

Comment: @uhoh On some research, you were most probably right, most likely what I saw was starlink train 12. Maybe due to some clouds on that part of the sky, 8 was unable to see the entire train. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RyugaGod You can consider leaving a short answer post with the same information that's in your comment. You can also click the "accept" checkmark. It's always satisfying when a question is answered and helps the sites statistics a little bit. Congratulations on seeing a train, I still haven't actually *seen one for real yet* :-)

Comment: on trying to click accept, it says to wait for 23 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some research, most likely what I saw was StarLink train 12. Maybe due to some clouds on that part of the sky, I was unable to see the entire train. Thanks.
Also, I do not know if I am right, this is what I thought, when I read [the launches page on this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink).